# Etherchannel configuration!

Tags: switch, switching, etherchannel, load-balancing, bridging

I´m trying to test this etherchannel configuration but did´t work properly.

The goal is:

I want to entablish a L2 communication channel between A and B, but i neet to put on the middle 2 equipments and try to load balance the traffic accross then. To do that i figure out the use of an etherchannel configuration like i described on the image, but did not work properly, i generate a lot of traffic and neither get to its destination

Any help will be appreciated[image]

Comment: @RonMaupin I´m trying this configuration with huawei equipment(switches) and servers like bridges. All the equipment is etherchannel capable in load balance and LACP mode

Comment: Is the trunk with 4 links in one single group or two seperate groups of 2 links?

Comment: On A and B, the trunk contains 4 links, but on bridges, one trunk have 2 links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have four bridges in a loop, but you want to load balance. The problem is that STP will block one direction in order to prevent layer-2 looping.

An etherchannel must start on one device, and terminate on another device. You cannot channel from one device through two other devices to a fourth device.

You can channel from A to each of the two middle bridges, but it will be two separate links, one to each of the middle bridges. The same goes for B to the middle bridges.

LACP is a link protocol that cannot be sent through a bridge. It is only between the two devices on each end of the physical link. LACP frames are sent with the special `01:80:c2:00:00:02` multicast MAC address. The IEEE has reserved the `01:80:c2` OUI for link protocols, and frames with this special multicast OUI are not allowed to be forwarded from the interface on which they are received to another interface on 802.1D compliant bridges.

Comment: From the bridge view, the 2 links on the 2 sides form a eth-trunk, then, one bridge will have 2 eth-trunk of 2 links each one, one to A and another to B.

Comment: With LACP I'm sure that did't work, 'cause LACP negotiation do never occurs, and trunk do never get UP

Comment: You need two LACP links on A and on B. Each channel goes to one intermediate bridge. For example, A should have one LACP link to the top bridge, and one LACP link to the bottom bridge. STP will block one of those links, and you cannot load balance across the intermediate bridges.

Comment: @OrlandoGaetano, The LACP links from A to the intermediate bridges must terminate on the intermediate bridges. You cannot channel from A to B.

Comment: I don't want to use LACP, only in normal mode, that's it, in load balance working mode, also i disabled STP and result is the same

Comment: I really don't understand. You need to channel to get load balancing, and you simply cannot have one channel across to separate bridges. Disabling STP is crazy. Channeling fools STP into thinking that multiple links are a single link. Channeling only works between the directly connected devices, and you can't channel from A to B. You can load balance on the individual links to each intermediate bridge, but not to both intermediate bridges. You cannot have one channel on A that encompasses both bridges.

Comment: Ok, i understand all things that our are explained here, but the think is, it is L2 traffic and the only path that can get is accross the bridges. Once traffic get into A, flows from multiples VLANs traffic, then it get the links to bridges, but they are on the etherchannel so nothing happens with STP, or I'm wrong?, then once they reach B, traffic are NATed and leaves B

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51542/discussion-between-orlando-gaetano-and-ron-maupin).